# Zabbix - change display of Unix timestamp value to human readable?

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-agent

I have a custom Item in Zabbix to check the date of the newest file in a particular folder. This is setup in Zabbix to store the data as "Numeric (unsigned)" with Data type "Decimal". This bit works fine, as does a trigger to check the age of the file and alert if greater than 24 hours.

However, to check the date of the file, I have go to "Latest Data" then get the timestamp value, then manually convert it to a d/m/Y human readable format.

Is there a way in Zabbix to change it's display value from Unix timestamp to datetime? I can see the value mappings facility, but it doesn't seem possible to use a function there.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the item unit to `unixtime`.